# D3JS - Combining "rect" functions

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

So I'm working on combining the following two features:

- [Brush and zoom, whit dragging and scroll zooming](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172)
- [Displaying values when hovered over](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/6eb506b129f585ce5c8a)

My main problem however is that they both use a "rect" object, and even if I append both of them, the one I appended later simply blocks the first one. The code for the two rects are the following:

This one is responsible for zooming:

```
  svg.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "zoom")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
      .call(zoom);
```

And this one is responsible for the hover-functions:

```
  svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "hoverRect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("pointer-events", "all")
    .on("mouseover", function() { focusDisplay.style("display", null); })
    .on("mouseout", function() { focusDisplay.style("display", "none"); })
    .on("mousemove", mousemove);
```

I tried combining the two of them, however this resulted the same as if I just appended the second one later (no zooming function, only the hover-actions):

```
  svg.append("rect")
    //.attr("class", "hoverRect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("pointer-events", "all")
    .on("mouseover", function() { focusDisplay.style("display", null); })
    .on("mouseout", function() { focusDisplay.style("display", "none"); })
    .on("mousemove", mousemove)
    .attr("class", "zoom")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .call(zoom);
```

If you have any idea, thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realised that the

```
.on("mousemove",mousemove)
```

Script was missing, that's the reason why it wasn't working.